# dart-polymer: cannot set an attribute from an event handler

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

The following code doesn't work. Maybe I do something wrong.. Please correct my code:

1. index.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <link rel="import" href="msg_box.html">
</head>
<body>
  <msg-box id="msg" caption="Caption 1"></msg-box>
  <button id="btn">click me</button>
<script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'msg_box.dart';

void main() {
  initPolymer();

  ButtonElement btn = querySelector("#btn");

  btn.onMouseEnter.listen((e) {
    MsgBoxElement elm = querySelector("#msg");

    window.alert(elm.caption); // SHOWS 'Caption 1'

    elm.caption = "Caption 2"; // DON'T WORK!

    window.alert(elm.caption); // SHOWS 'Caption 2', BUT PAGE SHOWS 'Caption 1'!!!
  });`
}
```

2. msg_box.html

```html
<polymer-element name="msg-box" attributes="caption">
  <template>
  <h4>{{caption}}</h4> 
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="msg_box.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('msg-box')
class MsgBoxElement extends PolymerElement {
  // fields
  String _caption;
  String get caption => _caption;
  void set caption(String value) {
    _caption = notifyPropertyChange(#caption, _caption, value);
  }

  MsgBoxElement.created() : super.created() {
  }
}
```

This issue is critical for me. See also https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14753&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that there are pending change notifications not being processed because your code is not running in the dirty-checking zone. There are two things you can do to fix this:

- call `Observable.dirtyCheck()` right after your update to `caption`; or,
- run your code within the dirty-checking zone:

```dart
void main() {
  var dirtyCheckingZone = initPolymer();
  dirtyCheckingZone.run(() {
     ButtonElement btn = querySelector("#btn");
     btn.onMouseEnter.listen((e) {
       MsgBoxElement elm = querySelector("#msg");
       elm.caption = "Caption 2";
    });
  });
}
```

This zone makes sure that after any callback or listener is executed, we'll call Observable.dirtyCheck for you. This approach is slightly better than calling dirtyCheck explicitly because, when we compile for deployment, we switch from dirty-checking to explicit notifications. The zone returned by initPolymer is changed to reflect this.

A separate note: the MsgBoxElement above can be simplified if you use the `@published` annotation. This is meant to express that a property is both observable and exposed as an attribute of your element.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('msg-box')
class MsgBoxElement extends PolymerElement {
  @published String caption;
  MsgBoxElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first approach works fine. The second one returns null (method run). therefore I got an exception.

Comment: Found the same issue.. I suggest to avoid using your own `main()` and keep using `polymer/init.dart` and then use `@CustomTag('msg-box')` and/or `@initMethod` to call your own methods.. remember `@initMethod` calls before `@CustomTag`...

Comment: what are downsides of running code with the dirty-checking zone? Are there alternatives to it? And more philosophical: why isn't it possible to create a proper constructor for a class inheriting from PolymerElement?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, it appears that the model is being updated, however the DOM isn't updating, most likely because an observable element isn't set. Try adding the following annotations to your `msg_box` dart code:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('msg-box')
class MsgBoxElement extends PolymerElement {
  // fields
  @observable String _caption;
  @reflectable String get caption => _caption;
  @reflectable void set caption(String value) {
    _caption = notifyPropertyChange(#caption, _caption, value);
  }

  MsgBoxElement.created() : super.created() {
  }
}
```

See this [Breaking change announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/web-ui/d94AR5cH2wc/discussion) on the dart mailing lists regarding the [@reflectable](http://api.dartlang.org/observe/Reflectable.html) attribute. Also see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/WJfH3bjri_s/SkSp4MUXDCUJ) on setting up [@observable](http://api.dartlang.org/observe/Observable.html) getters

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in the current version of dart-polymer (0.8.10)